# Error C3861: 'ResGain': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, undeclared-identifier

essentially I'm writing a short script. The easiest way to look at is that it's for a game with a resource collection. ResGain is the resources gained, and BonusGain is the chance to earn an extra resource. I am getting Identifier not found errors for the ResGain and Bonus Gain functions, but I have declared the ResGain and BonusGain functions before main. Any ideas why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


float ResGain(float u, int r) //calc Base resource Gain
    {
        float lapout;

        lapout = r * u;

        return (lapout);
    }

char BonusGain(int b) //Determines if a bonus material would be produced. 
{
    char bonus;
    int rng;

    rng = rand() % 100 + 1;

    if (rng <= b)
        bonus = 1;
    return(bonus);
}


int main()
{
    float l;

    l = ResGain(1.1,70);

    cout << "You have earned" << l << "Lapis";
    if (BonusGain(3)==1)
        cout << "You have also earned a bonus material";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the identifier not found is `system()` which is not part of the standard library. You should locate the Windows-specific header where it is declared.